# set value from two select query in one array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

my two select query is like this but i want to fetch all records in single array  how it is possible to set all values in one array from different select query

```
    $partyId = isset($_REQUEST['partyId']) ? $_REQUEST['partyId'] : 0;

    $k = 0;
    $clientDetail = array();
    $selectClient = "SELECT * FROM client
                     WHERE partyId = ".$partyId;
    $selectClientRes = mysql_query($selectClient);
    while($clientRow = mysql_fetch_array($selectClientRes))
    { 
      $clientDetail[$k]['clientId']     = $clientRow['clientId'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['particular']   = $clientRow['particular'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['cliTransType'] = $clientRow['cliTransType'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['cDate']        = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($clientRow['cDate']));
      $clientDetail[$k]['rate']         = $clientRow['rate'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['diff']         = $clientRow['diff'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['diffAmt']      = $clientRow['diffAmt'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['total']        = $clientRow['total'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['kg']           = $clientRow['kg'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['totalAmt']     = $clientRow['totalAmt'];
    }

    $rojmelArray = array();
    $l = 0;
    $selectRojmel = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(rojmelDate,'%d-%m-%Y') AS rojmelDate,fine AS rojmelFine,amount AS rojmelAmt,rojTransType 
                        FROM rojmel
                    WHERE partyId = ".$partyId;
    $selectRojmelRes = mysql_query($selectRojmel);
    while($rojmelRow = mysql_fetch_array($selectRojmelRes))
    {
      $rojmelArray[$l]['rojmelDate']   = $rojmelRow['rojmelDate'];                 
      $rojmelArray[$l]['rojmelFine']   = $rojmelRow['rojmelFine'];                 
      $rojmelArray[$l]['rojmelAmt']    = $rojmelRow['rojmelAmt'];                 
      $rojmelArray[$l]['rojTransType'] = $rojmelRow['rojTransType'];                 
      $l++;
    }
```

for first query section

```
 {section name="sec" loop=$clientDetail}
     <td><a href="client.php?clientId={$clientDetail[sec].clientId}"><img src="img/edit.png"></a></td>
     <td>{$clientDetail[sec].particular}</td>
     <td>{$clientDetail[sec].cDate}</td>
     <td>{$clientDetail[sec].rate}</td>
     <td>{$clientDetail[sec].total}</td>
     <td>{$clientDetail[sec].kg}</td>
     <td>{$clientDetail[sec].totalAmt}</td>
  </tr>
  {/section}
```

Second query section

```
{section name="sec1" loop=$rojmelArray}
    {if $rojmelArray[sec1].rojTransType == 'J' }
      <td>Javak</td>
    {else}
      <td>Aavak</td>
    {/if}
     <td>{$rojmelArray[sec1].rojmelDate}</td>
     <td>{$rojmelArray[sec1].rojmelFine}</td>
     <td>{$rojmelArray[sec1].rojmelAmt}</td>
```

Comment: Please **stop** using the ***deprecated*** `mysql` extension, ***read [the red warning box](http://php.net/mysql_connect) on every doc-page***. The extension is deprecated, issues notices on the current PHP versions, and will be removed in the future. Learn to use `PDO` or `mysqli` (the `i` stands for _improved_), and learn about injection and prepared statements

Comment: Consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: i do not know how to use pdo @JayBlanchard

Comment: There is a link to a tutorial there @Prashant

Answer (score 0):

Try a left outer join which will marry results from the two tables where the clientId in the client table is equal to the partyId in the rojmel table.

```
$sql = "SELECT client.*, DATE_FORMAT(rojmelDate,'%d-%m-%Y') AS rojmelDate, fine AS rojmelFine, amount AS rojmelAmt, rojTransType FROM client LEFT OUTER JOIN rojmel on rojmel.partyId = clientId WHERE clientId = ".$clientId;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '".$partyId' at line 3

Comment: Try as one line and change last partyId to clientId

Comment: i have partyid field in both table

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: SELECT client.*, DATE_FORMAT(rojmelDate,'%d-%m-%Y') AS rojmelDate, fine AS rojmelFine, amount AS rojmelAmt, rojTransType FROM client LEFT OUTER JOIN rojmel on rojmel.partyId = clientId WHERE `clientId`= 2 @JustAspMe i get result with this

Comment: Very good.  I've updated the answer as requested by @Jay.  Please mark this as the answer if it worked for your needs.

Comment: i want to separate that records with rojTransType  and client transaction type how It's possible @JustAspMe

Comment: You can filter by adding a where statement.  So append to the end of the where clause " AND rojTransType = 'J' AND cliTransType = 'I'"...  Can you mark my answer please?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i get my result with this query

```
SELECT client.*, DATE_FORMAT(rojmelDate,'%d-%m-%Y') AS rojmelDate, fine AS rojmelFine, amount AS rojmelAmt, rojTransType FROM client 
LEFT OUTER JOIN rojmel on rojmel.partyId = clientId WHERE client.`partyId`= ".$partyId;
```